# "System tray" integration for Pidgin

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, pidgin

Is there a way to have a regular "system tray" icon for Pidgin in Gnome Shell?

With the Gnome Shell Extension, it does not work so smooth and I cannot open the contacts list with clicking on it.